# accessing the children views of a View in Android

Tags: java, android

I am quite new to Java, let alone Android. I am stuck with a problem
that I encountered while instrumenting (using the instrumentation
framework of android) the code of a Android project. I have a ListView
and using the getTouchables() API I have store the view in a
ArrayList. When in debug session, I saw that each view has children
(mChildren) when expanded I could see that there is a "ImageView" and
"TextView" present. when the "TextView" is expanded, I could access
the mText variable which contains the text value I am looking for. In
brief, the value I am looking for, when looking at the "variables"
window of the debug perspective of Eclipse, is present at 
'myview->mChildren->[1] (TextView)->mText->value'

Here "myview" is the name of the object of View class.

how do I access/ read the content of the "value" variable?

Please let me know if you need any info in this regard?

Thank you
-BA

Answer (score 0):

You could access via the findViewByID method of the mView object;

For example

```
TextEdit mText = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.mText);
mText.setText("Hello!");
```

Hope that's what you're after or helps.

Damon

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am trying to read the value present in the variable and not set it. The value of variable that I am trying to read is not in "R".